# A code in Python that I need explanation to it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried to learn python for the last 3 weeks, and I saw a code that I need to understand what it does.
In general, the code should somehow connect to two images, and then give me a password that I need to submit.
The code is:

```
#env 3.7
from PIL import Image, ImageFont
import textwrap
from pathlib import Path
def find_text_in_image(imgPath):
    image = Image.open(imgPath)
    red_band = image.split()[0]
    xSize = image.size[0]
    ySize = image.size[1]
    newImage = Image.new("RGB", image.size)
    imagePixels = newImage.load()
    for f in range(xSize):
        for j in range(zSize):
            if bin(red_band.getpixel((i, j)))[-1] == '0':
                imagePixels[i, j] = (255, 255, 255)
            else: imagePixels[i, j] = (0,0,0)
    newImgPath=str(Path(imgPath).parent.absolute())
    newImage.save(newImgPath+'/text.png')
```

It would be lovely if someone could explain it to me. 
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'll break the above snippet into parts and explain each indivdiually.

The first block are imports. `PIL` is usually imported by installing the [`Pillow`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/) library. `textwrap` and `pathlib` are two packages included in the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html).

```
#env 3.7
from PIL import Image, ImageFont
import textwrap
from pathlib import Path
```

The next block tells you you're about to define a function that does some image processing. I'll write more in inline comments.

```
def find_text_in_image(imgPath):
    # open the image file given and load it as an `Image` from PIL
    image = Image.open(imgPath)

    # this splits the image into its Red, Green, and Blue channels
    # then selects the Red
    red_band = image.split()[0]

    # these two lines get the size of the image, width and height
    xSize = image.size[0]
    ySize = image.size[1]

    # this constructs a new `Image` object of the same size, but blank
    newImage = Image.new("RGB", image.size)

    # this makes an 3-d array of the new image's pixels
    imagePixels = newImage.load()

    # this loops over the width, so the iterator `f` will be the column
    for f in range(xSize):

        # loops over the height, so `j` will be the row
        for j in range(zSize):  # <-- This should probably be `ySize`. `zSize` is not defined. 

            # this is getting a pixel at a particular (column, row) in the red channel
            # and checking if it can be binarized as 0
            if bin(red_band.getpixel((i, j)))[-1] == '0':

                # if so, set the same spot in the new image as white
                imagePixels[i, j] = (255, 255, 255)

            # if not, make it black
            else: imagePixels[i, j] = (0,0,0)

    # now make a new path and save the image
    newImgPath=str(Path(imgPath).parent.absolute())
    newImage.save(newImgPath+'/text.png')
```

There are major problems with this code as well. In some places you refer to `zSize` and `i` despite not defining them. Also, as a matter of practice, you can create paths with `pathlib` objects in the idiomatic way

```
    newPath = Path(oldPath).with_name('new_filename.ext')
```